# How to prove that a matrix is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this problem:
Given a diagonal $n \times n$ matrix $A$, and $P$ is a matrix such that for every column and every row there is $n-1$ zeroes and $1$ ones for each.
Prove that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix ($P^{-1}$ is the inverse of $P$).

Can I conclude from the given that $P$ is an involutory matrix, and can I continue with that direction to prove? If I cant then I'll appreciate if you direct me to another way of proving this.

Comment: What matrix satisfies the condition: for every column and every row, there are $n - 1$ zeroes and a single $1$?

Comment: yes in other words that every row has zeroes and only a single 1 ,and same for columns.

Comment: Can you construct an example of such a matrix?

Comment: P=([1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]) for example

Comment: Do there exist any other examples?

Comment: Here is another one P=([0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]) in these examples P is 3x3 it can be any nxn.

Comment: (The following is not a derivation, merely an explanation.) Such a matrix $P$ is said to be a _permutation_ matrix; multiplying on the left permutes the rows, and multiplying on the right permutes the columns. The effect of $PAP^{-1}$ on a diagonal matrix $A$ is therefore simply to permute the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P$ is called a "Permutation Matrix". Let $\sigma \in \mathbb{S}_n$ be the permutation such that $\sigma(i) = j$ when the $j^{th}$ entry of the $i^{th}$ column of $P$ is $1$. You should try to prove that $\sigma^{-1}$ is the permutation that you would get from doing the same construction with $P^{-1}$.

Let $A_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ column of $A$ and $e_k$ be the $k^{th}$ standard basis vector. Then:

\begin{align*}
 P^{-1}APe_k &= P^{-1}Ae_{\sigma(k)} \\
&= P^{-1}A_{\sigma(k)} \\
&= a_{\sigma(k),\sigma(k)} e_{\sigma^{-1}(\sigma(k))}\\
&= a_{\sigma(k),\sigma(k)} e_k \\
\end{align*}

Here $a_{i,j}$ denotes the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $A$. Note that $P^{-1}APe_k$ is the $k^{th}$ column of $P^{-1}AP$. Therefore $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal. In particular, all you did was mix up the diagonal entries of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up but im new to this so i dont understand some of the notations that you wrote,what does  σ(i) mean?

Comment: $\sigma$ is a function from the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to itself. So $\sigma(i)$ means the value that $\sigma$ takes at the point $i$. By $\sigma^{-1}$ I mean the inverse of $\sigma$ as a function.

Comment: If you want to read a bit about [Permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).